# Cannot Run Raster Calculation Using GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, osgeo

I am having some trouble running a raster calculation through GDAL. I am attempting to convert a raster to `dB` through the equation below.

A = my raster file

```
"10*log10(power(A,2))-83"
```

Using `gdal_calc` it looks like the following.

```
C:\>gdal_calc.py -A "C:\Users\moses\Desktop\Calc_Test\test444.img" 
--outfile="C:\Users\moses\Desktop\Calc_Test\test555.img" 
--calc="10*log10(power(A,2))-83" --debug --overwrite
```

I have attempted to do this in separate pieces. So, raise the raster to the second power, then get log10 of that result. But each time that I do this i recieve the following error...

> :1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10

Any idea on how I might go about resolving this?

Thanks in advance for any potential help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently some of your pixel values contain zeros. 
So if you take `log10(0)`, it returns `-Inf` which causes the error.

**Try this:**

```
C:\>gdal_calc.py -A "C:\Users\moses\Desktop\Calc_Test\test444.img" --outfile="C:\Users\moses\Desktop\Calc_Test\test555.img" --calc="10*log10(power(A+0.0001,2))-83" --debug --overwrite
```

Or set your 0 values to NA.

Comment: Is it possible to assign it as noData if such error happens?